# Does SQS trigger lambda in an async / sync manner?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Will a standard SQS that I configured to invoke a lambda when it receives message invoke "many lambdas" or only 1 lambda at a time?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html):

> Lambda polls the queue and invokes your function **synchronously** with an event that contains queue messages.

It will invoke as many as [required](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html), depending on your [reserved concurrency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html#configuration-concurrency-reserved) limits:

> Lambda increases the number of processes that are reading batches by up to 60 more instances per minute. The **maximum number of batches that can be processed simultaneously by an event source mapping is 1000**.

Comment: So when to configure async lambda invocation? what is the use case?